# Who are those in the 7th level of Gehinnom?

Tags: gehinnom

I have heard about the 7 levels of gehinnom, if I am not wrong from a book call Reshit Chochma by Rabbi Eliyahu DaVidas. I don't have the book and didn't find it online.

Is there any English translation of it?

Comment: https://www.hidabroot.org/article/80185 but please don't ask me to explain. Use Google translate if you care enough...

Comment: Buddy, you might recall your question [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/96927/15571).

Comment: Only if we could have it online

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no English translation of *Reshit Chochmah* (Gates of fear) last time I looked... there is one of Gates of love.

From my notes (not saying this list is complete) [Names of each level are mentioned in Me'am Loez in *Parsha Bereshis*]  [Eruvin 19a says *Avadon* (annihalation) instead of Duma mentioned in *me'am loez* translation] *Vilna Gaon* says Avadon is the seventh level and sheol represents the first six levels in a general sense in commentary on misheli 27:20]

**Level 1:** *Bor shaon* (pit of turbulent waters)

Someone who interrupts his torah study to engage in idle chatter, someone who doesn't honor *talmidei chachamim*, someone who curses a deaf person or the like, someone who says good things about someone in front of his enemy (causing him to say lashon hara)

**Level 2** *Beer Shachath* (Well of Destruction)

Someone who honors himself through putting down someone else, someone who knows his friend is going to stumble in halacha and he doesn't tell him and they're both in the same city, someone who has a shul in his city and doesn't go there to pray, someone who lifts his hand to hit his friend even though he doesn't hit him, someone who insults his friend and causes him embarassment

**Level 3** *Dumah*

Insulting Torah Scholars. Letzim (scoffers) of Torah/Talmud, scholars who are arrogant in their torah study, someone who judges others negatively (*l'kaf chova*), lends money with *ribis*, doesn't say amen after someone's blessing, interrupts his davening and talks, old scholar who forgot his torah learning (through neglect)

**Level 4:** *tyt hayaven* - Quicksand/mire

Motzei Shem Ra, Rechillut. (By Nega Tzaarath). (in addition to level 3). People who don't greet shabbat and festivals. arrogant people (gasei ruach), someone who speaks harshly to the poor and the downtrodden, someone who sees a poor man in a tough situation and doesn't lend him money, someone who oppresses his employee (oshek schar sachir), a man who wastes seed unintentionally because he didn't intentionally guard his eyes (motzi zera lbatala b'shgeg), someone who has relations with a gentile or a nida, a judge who corrupts justice or takes a bribe. (from Zohar Chadash Ruth 79a quoted from Reishis Chachma - Shaar Yira Ch.13)

**Level 5** *Sheol*

Eating Orlah. Failure to circumcise. Defiling Brit through Arayos. heretics denying torah says/doesn't say such and such. Damaging Brit Milah homosexuals. One Punishment mentioned Burn't into ashes--put them back together. repeat

**Level 6** - Death Shadow/*Tzalmavet*

Relations with *nidah*, incest. kissing non relative. Prutzot. Wigs. A Robber (who stole everything from a poor person got 400 years.) An Author of Book writing about incest -- caused multitudes to sin. The angel couldn't even tell them how long they had left.

**Level Seven** *Eretz tachtith* - lower earth / underworld

.motzi zera lbatala bmezid/wasting seed intentionally, public Shabbos desecration, and machetei haraabim (causing masses to sin)

See https://youtu.be/DxYGqSV-gIo
And 
 https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=79772

http://www.dafyomireview.com/gehinom.php

Minchat Yehuda from r' Yehuda fetaya ztl has details of kaf hakela as well

Comment: Most of this doesn't answer the question at hand, which asked for an English translation of this Sefer, not who's in each level of Gehennom.

Comment: @DonielF in fairness the title of the question does ask for this

Comment: Hi Spr22, Can you please send me a link to access the one on Dafyomireview?

Comment: @Rh Haokip:  I put in a doc here for you: https://gofile.io/?c=GkGzv2

Comment: Spr22 Toda rabba