# English translation of Reshit Chochmah

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mussar-ethics, english

Is there an English translation of the book Reshit Chochmah By Rabbi Eliyahu DaVidas?

Comment: See [here](https://smile.amazon.com/Beginning-Wisdom-Translation-Hebrew/dp/096622664X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1542203401&sr=8-2&keywords=abraham+ibn+ezra) on amazon and [here](https://books.google.es/books?id=G_x6gl8SEeEC&pg=PA341&lpg=PA341&dq=reshit+hokhma+english&source=bl&ots=wwC2KzBcfp&sig=LHVi6ZRIm_A2DZGnr6Aj_n3qwbo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPkYb4gtTeAhXG_qQKHVAlB1UQ6AEwBXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=reshit%20hokhma%20english&f=false) on Google

Comment: @mbloch it is so interesting that you immediately gave a link to the lesser known work, as opposed to the well-known Reishis Chochma by Vidas.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned earlier by @Avrohom Yitzchok, there is an [English translation](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/The_Beginning_of_Wisdom.html?id=3bzSBSFw0q8C&redir_esc=ye&q&f=false) published by Ktav Publishing (2001) and translated by Simcha Benyosef.

Seems to be [out of stock](http://mysefer.com/The-Beginning-of-Wisdom---Reshit-Chochmah__p-3861.aspx) in most bookstores but you can still find it used in [some](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881256951) [book](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=30076037219&cm_ven=sws&cm_cat=sws&cm_pla=sws&cm_ite=30076037219&clickid=TYjygcxYy0rzQzIzNkXchytvUkgRqfRf9xVdz00&cm_mmc=aff-_-ir-_-353196-_-77798&ref=imprad353196&afn_sr=impact) [retailers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/088125696X).